# Joining two Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

trying to join two Kstreams but I am getting type mismatch error below is the code snippet.

```
  KStream<String, String> longCounts = netExpence.join(netIncome, (key1, key2) -> key1 + "/" + key2,                    JoinWindows.of(joinWindowSizeMs).until(windowRetentionTimeMs),stringSerde, stringSerde, stringSerde);
```

The error that comes is **Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to R**
This is the syntax for joining the kstreams `join(KStream<K,VO> otherStream, ValueJoiner<? super V,? super VO,? extends VR> joiner, JoinWindows windows, Joined<K,V,VO> joined)`

please explain what exactly `ValueJoiner<? super V,? super VO,? extends VR>` does..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueJoiner` is called with the two values of the matching records and emit an join result value.

```java
// key type must be the same for a join
// value type can be different
KStream<KeyType, ValueType1> stream1 = ...
KStream<KeyType, ValueType2> stream2 = ...

KStream<KeyType, OutputType> joined = stream1.join(stream2, ...);
```

Thus, `ValueJoiner` must have `ValueType1` as first generic (`? super V`), and `ValueType2` as second generic (`? super VO`). For the third generic (`? extend VR`) you specify the output type (ie, `OutputType` from the example above).

**Update**

You also need to configure correct Serdes for runtime. If all type are the same, it's best to set the default serdes via `StreamsConfig` for key and/or value accordingly. Otherwise, you can overwrite the default Serdes per operator:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#default-key-serde
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html

Comment: Thanks,but the data type for all the three V,VO wnd VR is string..I have mentioned the same but getting type cast error..

Comment: Not sure. Your Question does not show `netIncome` -- I guess it's `KStream<String,String>` ? Can you share the full compiler error? It's unclear to me, why it says `String to R` -- not sure what `R` is...

Comment: This is the key value data type of netIncome and netExpence
KStream<String, String> netExpence and KStream<String, String> netIncome

Comment: Please check what your default serdes for key and value are? You can try setting it to Serdes.String. Or else, provide the serdes while performing the join.